# How to update tags under existing vocabulary in ckan?

Tags: python, ckan

I recently added some tags to my existing vocabulary , but even after restarting my ckan application the new tags were not getting reflected in my UI(vocabulary is a select box and the tags are the different options under it , recently added two more options).
I was able to get the new tags only when I deleted the vocabulary and tags from the backend and restarted the application

is there any way to update my tag list , without a backend hack?

Comment: How did you create the vocabulary? Most examples (like this one in the [official documentation](http://docs.ckan.org/en/latest/extensions/adding-custom-fields.html#tag-vocabularies)) create the dictionary _after checking it does not exist already_: if it exists, the tag creation code is not run.